Button se desaalinea con el resto al escribir caracteres que generan multilinea
Uso Kotlin sobre Android Studio. El diseño del activity_main con xml, es un Sudoku que, con 81 Button (TextSize = 16sp), tiene 9 filas y 9 columnas, agrupados de 3 en 3, de tal manera que resultan 9 zonas diferentes. Un sudoku clásico. Los button serían las 'celdillas' del sudoku.
He habilitado, por programación, cada Button para, tras una pulsación larga, recoger diferentes 'candidatos' que el usuario quiera escribir. Cuando ocupan más de una 'línea' del Text los escribe sin problema. Al volver a arrancar o volver a cargar me descompone todo el GridLayout —entiendo que es por 'falta' de sitio— por los Button que llevan 'multilínea'.
Se observa arriba a la derecha cómo se han reacomodado los button ó celdillas del sudoku.

He probado a cambiar TextSize a 13sp y no se soluciona: siempre que tiene que 'saltar' de 'línea' dentro del button sucede lo mencionado: se descompone el gridLayout al reiniciar o recargar.
Les paso el xml completo hasta la parte que contiene 2 Button, y así hasta 81 de ellos. Luego cierro los gridLayout, etc. y va algo de código adicional, pero que no afecta a éste.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/almenarasunset"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!--ZONA INICIO, PUNTOS, NUEVO -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_nivel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="  Nivel        :"
        android:textColor="#100101"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tiempo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_nivel"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="  Record T :"
        android:textColor="#100101"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_jugados"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_tiempo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Jugados   :"
        android:textColor="#100101"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ganados"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_jugados"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Ganados  :"
        android:textColor="#150000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_perdidos"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_ganados"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Perdidos  :"
        android:textColor="#120000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />
    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/cronometro"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.60"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.70"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/superior"
        android:text="SUDOKU Almenara"
        android:background="#00AABBCC"
        android:textColor="#FBFAFA"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/acciones"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#16665D75"
        android:tooltipText="Acciones"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/superior"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/pngwingrojo"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_acciones"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/acciones"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Acciones"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_mensajes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="40dp"
        android:justificationMode="inter_word"
        android:text="Avisos"
        android:textColor="#0947FF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/grid00" />



    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/superior"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    </GridLayout>
<!--  ===========================================
=================================================
ZONA CUADRICULAS ================================-->
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"

        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/superior"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
<!-- ZONA 1º CUADRICULA-->
        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="3">
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/b01"
                android:layout_width="39dp"
                android:layout_height="43dp"
                android:background="@drawable/greyborder"
                android:textSize="16sp"

                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b02"
                android:layout_width="39dp"
                android:layout_height="43dp"
                android:background="@drawable/greyborder"
                android:textSize="16sp"

                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

...



Agrega una imagen de como se muestra desalineado el texto.
